# unity3d and webgl comparison in terms of performance and speed

Tags: performance, opengl-es, unity-game-engine

I am gonna develop a lesson in two platforms(firstly in webgl and then a similar lesson in unity 3d).
the aim of this research is to see the best of these platforms in terms of performance and speed to use it in e-learning environments.

my question is this :

how can i measure the performance (processor, memory,  graphic card) for these platforms?

also, I am very appreciated if any one give me ideas or a suggestions to improve this research.

Answer (score 3):

WebGL and Unity are not platforms. Unity is a library that has support for *multiple* platforms; its performance depends on what hardware its running on. WebGL is a JavaScript API for browsers that allow them to access OpenGL ES 2.0. This also isn't a platform; it is utterly dependent on the hardware it is running on.

Sure, each incurs overhead, but they also do completely different things. Even if one is seen as faster for a particular piece of hardware, that doesn't mean that you can use it. Unity makes applications. Something you download and install. WebGL is for web pages: HTML+JavaScript. The reasons to use one are not the same reasons you would have to use the other.

Making a "WebApp" is very different from making a regular application. You generally decide first off whether you want to make a WebApp or a regular application, then use the tools that are available to the one you pick.

There are platforms that don't support WebGL. Namely, Internet Explorer. Microsoft has already stated that they aren't going to implement WebGL. So WebGL's performance on IE is effectively 0.

Also, WebGL is a low-level rendering API; Unity is a game engine. Unity provides more functionality towards making a game than WebGL, so there are productivity differences you must take into account.

Your desire to compare the performance of these simply is not the most useful criteria for deciding which one to use.

---

OK, your later answer clued me in to the idea that you're focusing on browser-based tools.

WebGL is not available on Internet Explorer. So again, half of your customer base is gone. However, Unity's browser plug-in is a plug-in and therefore must be downloaded by the user. Quite a few users are against that. Also, Unity's browser plug-in doesn't work on mobile systems; you would be expected to write an app for those.

So which matters more to you: reaching out to mobile users (where WebGL is available), or reaching out to Internet Explorer users? Again, this is something you need to deal with long before you answer questions of performance.

Comment: @kreem: ... is what? Did you mean to post something more there?